# Infinite chain ordered by inclusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does there exists an infinite chain in $P(\mathbb{N})$ ordered by inclusion?

I think that no because we have always add at least one element but its not a proof so I'm not sure.

Comment: What is $P(\Bbb N)$?

Comment: There is both an increasing and a decreasing (countably)infinite chain in $\mathbb N$ by inclusion. The add-one each time gives an increasing chain, and "remove-one" from $\mathbb N$ each time gives a decreasing chain. (I think $P(\mathbb N)$ is the power set of $\mathbb N$). As for *uncountably* infinite, I think you should think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a (countably) infinite chain by inclusion: Let $Z_d = \{n | n$ is divisible by $d\}$.

$Z_2 \supset Z_4 \supset Z_8 \supset \ldots \supset Z_{2^k}  \supset \ldots$